# FlaskWTF same form on every view / page

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms

in my Flask Project i have configured a `basepage.html` Jinja template every other page inherits from.
In this `basepage.html` i want to have a Search bar at the top, so that it also appears at every page inheriting from it.

The input from this search form (is a form even the best way to do it?) should be processed 
by the routing function `search()` I defined as follows:

views.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('Dashboard.html') #Dashboard.html inherits from basepage.html

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET' ,'POST'])
def search():
    search_query = #input from search-bar
    result = #get data matching search_query from database
    return render_template('Search.html', results = results) #Search.html extends basepage.html
```

forms.py excerpt:

```
class Search(FlaskForm):
    search_query = StringField('Search for ...')
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

Is there a way i can have my Search form on every page, so when i enter my query in the bar at the top of the Dashboard form and press enter the search_query gets processed by the `search()` view?

Answer (score 2):

Just create your searchbar template code in a partial file located at `/templates/includes/my_searchbar.html` or whatever you want to name it and then in your base template just place an includes directive wherever you want the search to render in, something like:

```
{% include 'includes/my_searchbar.html' %}
```

If the searchbar is included in base and all your other templates inherit from base, then search will be included on all pages.

All of your routes will also need to have the Search() form class included so they have access to the form, so you will need to modify your routes something like:

```
from app.forms import Search #if you defined Search in /app/forms.py

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    search_form = Search() #initialize an instance of the form
    return render_template('Dashboard.html', search_form=search_form)
```

Then you can use `search_form` in your `includes/my_searchbar.html` partial to render the form. Maybe something like:

```
<form class="form" method="post" role="form">
    {{ search_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ search_form.search_query }}
    {{ search_form.submit }}
</form>
```

Comment: Would not it be a better design, of instead doing the search form as a html component? That way you can still include it wherever you need using Jinja syntax, but you wont have to have search_form = Search() in every single route. Thus you could have a separate function that does the search query only , and it is separated from your other view logics? @chase

Comment: @AkibRhast that's certainly an evolutionary step in the refactoring process. From the sample code OP provided it's not clear that they grasp the relationship between templates, forms, and routes, so I'm just trying to walk them through one step at a time. Having something globally included like that is a bad example to start with so it makes sense to try and iterate rather than jump right into deeper concepts.

Comment: ah, i see what you had in mind now. thank for taking the trouble to explain :D